# I lost Android SDK & ADT from eclipse after installing eGit

Tags: android, eclipse, egit

Today i installed eGit from eclipse & than restart the eclipse & my Android SDK & ADT icons were gone from eclipse.
Starting SDK manager & AVD manager from WINDOW.
I tried to change perspectives,but can not get back.
I also tried to customize the perspective but i can't find anything related to ANDROID anywhere.
I can't reinstall the ADT because it says,"It is already installed."

Though all sdks are saved in the dirctory & i can access them there.But can't find it in eclipse.

Comment: try eclipse-> window -> preferences the click on Android left on side and give the android sdk location and apply

Comment: i can't find android anywhere in the eclipse.
that is the main problem.

Comment: restart the eclipse and again try same or click of icon of android that is show in left side of eclipse

Comment: as i said above.
I can't find anything related to android after restarting eclipse almost 10 times.

Comment: after re-installing eclipse & android sdk from my back up, i solved my problem.